# What is the delay of the YouTube live stream for ISS?

Tags: iss, communication, time

On YouTube, we can see a live stream from ISS.

What is the delay here (given you have a modern high speed internet access)?

Comment: The answers show that the stream you've linked to is not the original. That's unfortunate, because the question (what is the delay) is an interesting one. you could consider replacing the video link with the official NASA one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPSdR_MSa8I to get the discussion back on track.

Answer (score 3):

This is a follow-up to my [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32611/what-is-the-delay-of-the-yt-live-stream-for-iss/32886#comment99675_32617) and to lend support to @Tristan's [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32617/12102).

I took a bunch of comparison screen shots over 30min of the two YouTube "live" channels in parallel, and I've made a little side-by-side montage of the two.

The alternate, non-NASA site in question is constantly switching to old footage from either previous passes of a nearby area or geographically unrelated areas.

While the site is called "**NASA Live: Earth From Space - Nasa Live Stream | ISS LIVE FEED**", it is definitely not that at all, except once in a while.

The site could be considered to have at least one foot in "sham territory" or be "borderline sham". It only appears that it might be live when the little white sign that says 'WWW.ISS-LIVE.COM` is on:

[image]

which isn't much of the time.

The "trip" shown below is from about `2018-12-06 23:54:00 UTC` to `2018-12-07 00:35:00 UTC` and passes over Australia diagonally northward and over the pacific towards Alaska/Canada, but sunset gets there first. Here's a screen shot of N2YO about half way through around `00:14:00 UTC`:

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That video is a sham.  It's not a live stream (except for the small ESA location map at the bottom center).

At the time of this screenshot, the ISS is on the night side of earth.

[image: NOT LIVE!]

Comment: *quod erat demonstrandum*

Comment: Not a sham, the video matches the specification on the Youtube page: "THIS WILL SHOW LIVE and PRE-RECORDED FOOTAGE - As the Space Station passes into a period of night every 45 mins video is unavailable - during this time, and other breaks in transmission, recorded footage is shown ."

Comment: It simply rehosts NASA content, (e.g., this live stream: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Va0tdqjZz-c ) and slaps an ad on it.  I view it as a cynical money grab with little value added.

Comment: I checked the NASA Youtube channel, and while I found an ISS live stream that could be the source for the top section of the screen, I didn't find a stream that shows the combined view seen here. Unless I've overlooked something, of course.

Comment: On further look, pretty much everything relevant is scraped from this page: http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Human_Spaceflight/International_Space_Station/Where_is_the_International_Space_Station -- the HDEV stream and the map.  The bottom left and bottom right videos are just time-lapse videos that NASA has produced and made available and aren't live anything.

Comment: @Hobbes I took a bunch of comparison screen shots over 30min and I'll format them somehow nicely soon. The site in question is constantly switching to old footage from either previous passes of a nearby area or geographically unrelated areas. The site is called "NASA Live: Earth From Space - Nasa Live Stream | ISS LIVE FEED" and it is definitely not that at all, except once in a while. I think it is in "sham territory" or "borderline sham" but that's just me.  It only appears that it might be live when the little white sign that says 'WWW.ISS-LIVE.COM` is on https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4PpD.png

Comment: @Hobbes see [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32886/12102).

Comment: @Tristan ditto.